# How to send mouse motions using SendMessage()

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I'm trying to write a simple windows form consists of buttons,
one of the buttons is sending mouse clicks to an active applications such as notepad. so I will click on button and the buttons will send the mouse events to the notepad or any application.

It only sends right-click or clicks,
I wrote this code for dll definitions:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd,uint Msg, int wParam,int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int FindWindow(String lbClassName,     StringlbWindowName);
```

// for events

```
private const uint WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
private const uint WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;
```

// event handler

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int window = FindWindow(null, "Notepad");
    SendMessage(window, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(window, WM_RBUTTONUP, 0, 0);
}
```

This doesn't work!!

How can I know it the mouse clicks sent?
And why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to correct your DllImport signatures...

```
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

Then you need to set a break point on your FindWindow call and check that it does indeed return an IntPtr that contains a window handle value.

Then run Spy++ and check that the Notepad has the same actual window handle as the one returned by your call. Setup Spy++ to log all messages to Notepad and see if it does indeed arrive at the target window.